# package.json vs. "npm install %s -g"

Tags: node.js, npm

A `package.json` example:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-node": ""
  }
}
```

It just won't work. Some errors like the following will appear:

> npm ERR! error rolling back Error: UNKNOWN, unlink '/vagrant/x/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters/ext/env.rhino.1.2.js'
>   npm ERR! error rolling back  jasmine-node@1.14.5 { [Error: UNKNOWN, unlink '/vagrant/x/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters/ext/env.rhino.1.2.js']
>   npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -1,
>   npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'UNKNOWN',
>   npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/vagrant/x/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters/ext/env.rhino.1.2.js' }
>   npm ERR! Error: UNKNOWN, symlink '../coffee-script/bin/coffee'
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
>   npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
>   npm ERR!     http://github.com/npm/npm/issues

But if I do `npm install jasmine-node -g`, everything install and works seamlessly and I can't see why.

Can someone clarify this question for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that line from `package.json` and do `npm install --save-dev jasmine-node` that will install it and add the correct line in your `devDependencies`.

Comment: `npm ERR! error rolling back Error: UNKNOWN, unlink '/vagrant/x/node_modules/jasmine-node/node_modules/jasmine-reporters/ext/env.rhino.1.2.js'` =(

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge try `rm node_modules -rf` or try in an empty folder, and try `npm cache clean`.

Comment: Ok it's related to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926416/socket-io-install-errors. Please accept if this link helps you.

Comment: I thought for a while that the problem could be on Windows + Vagrant, but I let it pass away. Ok, it worked – thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
sudo npm install jasmine-node@1.14.2 -g
```

Current version is `1.14.3`, so it is one version behind.

In package.json try:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-node": ">=1.14.3"
    "jasmine-reporters": "~1.0.0",
  }
}
```

Comment: No success as well, same error as I commented to @facebook.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Manwal, but the problem was with Windows + Vagrant environment. And just to notice you, `jasmine-reporters` is a direct dependency of `jasmine-node`, as you can see [here](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node/blob/master/package.json#L27). Thank you by the bye!